# Unable to run SSIS package in BIDS 2008 after uninstalling Visual studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

After removing Visual Studio 2013 from my Windows 7 32 bit machine, I receive
 the following 4 errors when trying to run a SSIS package in BIDS 2008:

1. **Error: 0xC020929A at Package1, Package1 (PipelineXml):** Unable to
   instantiate XML DOM document,  please verify that MSXML binaries are
   properly installed and  registered.
2. **Error: 0xC020821F at Package1, Package1 (PipelineXml):** Unable to
   load from XML.
3. **Error: 0xC0040041 at Package1, Package1 (SSIS.Pipeline):** Failed to
   load Data Flow objects
4. **Error: 0xC0010018 at Package1:** Failed to load task "Package1", type
   "SSIS.Pipeline.2".   The contact  information for this task is
   "Performs high-performance data  extraction, transformation and
   loading;Microsoft Corporation;  Microsoft SQL Server v10; (C) 2007
   Microsoft Corporation; All Rights 
   Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1".

I've researched items on the web and have tried the following to no avail:

- Repaired BIDS 2008
- Re-installed BIDS 2008
- Re-installed SQL Server 2008 R2
- Re-installed *MSXML 4.0 SP2 Parser and SDK*
- Created new package

I have BIDS 2008, VS 2010 and VS 2012 installed on this machine.

Any insight on how to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I've run MS Process Monitor using both BIDS 2008 and SSIS Execution Utility. The results are below:

**Packaged launched from BIDS:**

[image]

**Package launched from SSIS Execution Utility:**

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the problem is not with BIDS being present, but with SSIS itself being present.  So, if have any SSIS packages in the "file system" (or can export one to the file system), then, on that machine, right-click one of them (a ".DSTX" file), and hover over "Open With"... do you see the package execution utility on the list?  If the problem is with SSIS itself, even re-installing SQL Server may NOT put it back.  Try going to Control Panel, Programs and Features, right-clicking on SQL Server 2008 R2, and selecting "Change", to install from there.  Install all, as if for a server.

Comment: If I run the package using "Package Execution Utility" it runs just fine with no errors. It seems to only have an issue going BIDS.

Comment: I realize this is not the solution you're looking for... but what if you re-install VS 2013?  Does BIDS 2008 resume working?

Comment: I re-installed VS 2013 and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: So, finding the DLLs, but not INI files...  and zero results, googling those 3 "INI" files (yeah... bet you tried that).  So, again not what you're looking for, but... what I would try next:  (1) Getting those INI files from somebody else's machine with BIDS 2008 working, (2) *Uninstalling* BIDS 2008 completely, before reinstalling it, and (3) Click the "submit feedback" button on the top left, at:  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=bids%202008%20not%20working%20after%20uninstalling%20vs%202013 -- you're offering a lot of info, to help them solve this.

Comment: How did this all play out?  Any resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a resolution. I've submitted info to Microsoft and outside of that, I've run out of ideas.

Comment: If you leave a link to the Microsoft submission, then people finding this question, having the same problem, can upvote/comment on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back and resolved it by installing SQL Server Data Tools for VS 2012. VS2012 without SSDT wouldn't load the ssis projects. After getting SSDT installed it did prompt me to upgrade my package from 2008 to 2012.

Comment: I failed to mention that I installed VS 2012 SSDT as a workaround. I really need to get BIDS 2008 back up and running considering it's the standard for my company.